# How to remove duplicate "Send to..."?

Tags: nautilus, 22.04, menu

For some reason I have duplicate "Send to..." in right click drop down menu. As far as I can see they do exactly the same, open Thunderbird and compose email from same address. I have just one Thunderbird installed. How could I possibly edit them and remove one of them?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Send to..." right-click menu option is provided by a python extension. Remove the "nautilus-sendto" package to remove (at least one) instance of the options you have.